# git for-each-ref fields syntax

Tags: git

I'm trying to understand the magic behind the object fields syntax, in particular the presence of the * prefix.

For example (note the *****authordate)

```sh
git for-each-ref --sort='-*authordate' --format='%(*authordate)'
```

Lists the dates as expected, while without a start

```sh
git for-each-ref --sort='-*authordate' --format='%(authordate)'
```

Shows no dates whatsoever, furthermore (note *****objecttype)

```sh
git for-each-ref --sort='-*authordate' --format='%(*authordate) -- TYPE: %(*objecttype)'
```

Returns `TYPE: commit`, whereas without a * the result will be `TYPE: tag`

Can somebody please explain the magic behind this syntax, I couldn' google it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [`git help for-each-ref`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref#Documentation/git-for-each-ref.txt---formatltformatgt):

> If `fieldname` is prefixed with an asterisk (`*`) and the ref points at a tag object, use the value for the field in the object which the tag object refers to (instead of the field in the tag object).

That is, `*` just dereferences tags, nothing more.

Comment: I see, thank you. Not clear when one would not want to dereference and get the value? I've seen many examples on the internet without using an asterisk, only the documentation examples uses it.

Comment: @user2964342: you leave the tag un-de-referenced (i.e., use the tag object itself) when you want to know something about the tag object itself: who made it, when, what sort of annotation message does it have in it, and so on. You use the target object when you want to know something about the target object: if it's a commit, who made it, when, etc. Some selectors like `%(authordate)` always find the commit anyway, but the `*` makes it clearer that you're doing that.

Comment: Note that `%(creator)` *does not* auto-deref a tag, but `%(author)` *does*.